# Using a Scheduled Job to delete generated sitemaps, Job not working

Tags: scheduled-tasks, sitemap

So, I have asked before about deleting my log files on my system after two days, got that question answered and after debating about it I thought maybe add a different patch that will delete my sitemap.xml after 7 days. Trying this out with a 5 min timer, nothing is working like it should. Not sure if it's the folder structure that I have it pointing to or the pattern I am looking for, but any help would be great. The sitemap name is like this too, `sitemap-TestUS.xml`

Here is the setting in my sitecore.config file for the variable name:

```
<sc.variable name="rootFolder" value="C:\home\site\wwwroot" />
```

Here is my patch

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="!Standalone">
    <scheduling>
      <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.CleanupAgent">
        <files hint="raw:AddCommand">
          <remove folder="$(rootFolder)">
            <patch:attribute name="pattern">*sitemap*</patch:attribute>
            <patch:attribute name="maxAge">5:00:00</patch:attribute>
            <patch:attribute name="recursive">true</patch:attribute>
          </remove>
        </files>
      </agent>
    </scheduling>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

###### Merged config:

[image: Showconfig]

Comment: Two questions: 1) Are you testing this on a local dev environment? 2) Can you share what the showconfig.aspx is showing after merging this patch config in?

Comment: Have you considered creating an in-memory version instead? No file to cleanup and faster response time.

Comment: So this is just out on test environment. Here is the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASiCg.png

Comment: What are your filenames for your sitemap? Maybe set the pattern to be more specific - say `*sitemap.xml`. Also, if I'm reading your config right, you have the `maxAge` set to 5 hours, not 5 minutes, and your clean up agent is running every 6 hours. If you must do this with a scheduled task, you'd be better off using `SiteCron` - its more accurate and stable than a scheduled task and you can be more specific about when it runs. Ultimately tho - you should follow Michael West's advice and create an in-memory version instead - or re-generate the sitemap on a publish:end

Comment: Ok so to follow up on your comment, my sitemaps are named sitemap-brand1us.xml, then there is a sitemap-brand2us.xml, etc. I might have about 9 difference sitemaps up there so was trying to be as generic as I could to catch them all. Second I was worried about the hours to mins however I let it sit over night and they are still there so even after 5 hours they didnt delete.

Comment: I think I am more in favor for the re-generate on a publish:end since that is really when I need them regenerated. I just didnt know anything about that so any news on that would be great. I figured I would just try this job and run every 7 days(NOT 5 hours) to almost get the same effect as publish.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the time for these agents gets reset any time there is a recycle of your app pool, using the agents can be fiddly if it's a long time in between runs. I'd follow Richard Seal's advice and use SiteCron if you want to run it as a job (but ideally use in-memory like Michael West is suggesting)